# Add column in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, jsp

I am using SQL Server 2005 and JSP. I want to add column having name as string object value.

```
String dr="Doctor1";

stat1=conn.createStatement();
stat1.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE dbo.PHPL ADD '"+dr+"' NVARCHAR(255) Null");
```

It is giving error near column name.I think I am mistaking with syntax. Please help.

Comment: `'` quotes are for strings. You want `"` for field names.

Answer (score 3):

```
String dr="Doctor1";

stat1=conn.createStatement();
stat1.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE dbo.PHPL ADD "+dr+" NVARCHAR(255) Null");
```

that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here

- You need to use [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), not `executeUpdate`. Altering a table is a DDL command, not insert, update or delete
- As KittenLS has pointed out, the syntax for `ALTER TABLE` doesn't need quotes. However, you should use '[]' around to escape spaces, keywords, etc.

i.e.

```
stat1.execute("ALTER TABLE dbo.PHPL ADD [" + dr + "] NVARCHAR(255) Null");
```